# Bitcoin Cash testnet version of insight API

Tags: api, bitcoin-cash

I was wondering if anyone know a testnet version of Insight API for Bitcoin Cash?

For mainnet there are those:

- https://bch-insight.bitpay.com/api/
- https://bch-bitcore2.trezor.io/api/

But I cannot find one for testnet.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Murch has voted to delete my answer but on the same link (blockdozer) which I mentioned in answer has option for bitcoin cash test network by clicking on ecurrency

Answer (score 3):

With a trial & error procedure I've found this one :-)

Prefix for APIs is https://test-bch-insight.bitpay.com/api

For example:
https://test-bch-insight.bitpay.com/api/addrs/2MzrMhMEPN9KYsZHgijMqekPa8kmvwsuEVm,2N1w811DgtWzjHdwtP1zzbXqJdh9vNK3sk9,2N3rs2KJBYxZQifg5TY6Bjb8CGcvmYTppsG/utxo

Comment: Returns 404. The root works but not the /api

Comment: That's only the base url, full api call works, I've edited comment adding one example

Comment: It's not working, any updates?

Answer (score 2):

Bitpay did a large refactor of Insight/Bitcore so both BTC and BCH run off the same backend. The new URLs are:

- Block explorer: https://insight.bitcore.io/#/BCH/mainnet/home
- API: https://api.bitcore.io/api/BCH/mainnet
- API Docs: https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore/blob/master/packages/bitcore-node/docs/api-documentation.md
- Swap `mainnet/testnet` and `BTC/BCH` slugs as required

Example: get UTXOs for some random address I grabbed out of a recent block:

```
$ curl -s https://api.bitcore.io/api/BCH/mainnet/address/qz09ljd3fthvuuasw3tchnhm8a5z5ppm9vc4t6s5pe/?unspent=true | jq

[
  {
    "_id": "5cae0b7912025b0a3983bf75",
    "chain": "BCH",
    "network": "mainnet",
    "coinbase": false,
    "mintIndex": 2,
    "spentTxid": "",
    "mintTxid": "81d1e58956eb5ba269ad3ac6394382825bd9d9b4d3a22eca03133eef19446b72",
    "mintHeight": 577661,
    "spentHeight": -2,
    "address": "qz09ljd3fthvuuasw3tchnhm8a5z5ppm9vc4t6s5pe",
    "script": "76a9149e5fc9b14aeece73b074578bcefb3f682a043b2b88ac",
    "value": 7000000,
    "confirmations": -1
  },
  {
    "_id": "5cae0f6212025b0a3988a698",
    "chain": "BCH",
    "network": "mainnet",
    "coinbase": false,
    "mintIndex": 0,
    "spentTxid": "",
    "mintTxid": "b8b72fa7defb89824f9c31d6294e3764c4675ac085668604113f4b6394d8cdde",
    "mintHeight": 577664,
    "spentHeight": -2,
    "address": "qz09ljd3fthvuuasw3tchnhm8a5z5ppm9vc4t6s5pe",
    "script": "76a9149e5fc9b14aeece73b074578bcefb3f682a043b2b88ac",
    "value": 1111,
    "confirmations": -1
  }
]
```

Comment: tesnet endpoints are still working!